# Can we clear up the [faq-proposed] tag?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

There are currently 13 questions tagged with [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed), the "staging ground" for posts before they become official [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts and are added to [the FAQ](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1280/community-faq-for-programming-puzzles-code-golf). [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) is not intended to be a permanent tag, more of a placeholder, yet of these 13 questions, the most active (in terms of tag edits) was [this one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17636/in-bash-can-i-use-non-coreutil-programs), where the tag was part of the initial question, almost 2 years ago.

While the FAQ isn't exactly the most visited page, it cannot hurt to keep it up to date and relevant, rather than having useful posts scattered around Meta.

I propose the following:

- We go through all 13 of these questions and either add them to the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) or remove the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag from them (and potentially update the questions and answers to some)
- We find any posts without either FAQ tag that could potentially be added to the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and add the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) to them

The 13 FAQ proposed questions are:

- [How does this site work?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13944/how-does-this-site-work)
- [New users' guides to golfing rules in specific languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/new-users-guides-to-golfing-rules-in-specific-languages)
- [In bash, can I use non-coreutil programs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17636/in-bash-can-i-use-non-coreutil-programs)
- [Useful External Resources](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10351/useful-external-resources)
- [How are bytes counted in assembly?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12339/how-are-bytes-counted-in-assembly)
- [Catalogue of Catalogues](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12374/catalogue-of-catalogues)
- [Is it OK to promote my own posts in chat?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10184/is-it-ok-to-promote-my-own-posts-in-chat)
- [Are two questions duplicates if they have different scoring rules?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/777/are-two-questions-duplicates-if-they-have-different-scoring-rules)
- [How long should I wait before accepting an answer?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/how-long-should-i-wait-before-accepting-an-answer)
- [General rules for custom languages and libraries](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10225/general-rules-for-custom-languages-and-libraries)
- [Should submissions be allowed to exit with an error?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/should-submissions-be-allowed-to-exit-with-an-error)
- [Default for Code Golf: Program, Function or Snippet?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet)
- [How do we deal with novel emerging/recurring challenge types?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1561/how-do-we-deal-with-novel-emerging-recurring-challenge-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this has gone unanswered for a couple of days, here are my thoughts on what to do with each of the 13 posts:

As a number of them should clearly, in my view, be added to the FAQ, I won't bother "justifying" them, as I believe it's pretty self-explanatory why I think so:

- [How does this site work?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13944/how-does-this-site-work)
- [New users' guides to golfing rules in specific languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/new-users-guides-to-golfing-rules-in-specific-languages)
- [How long should I wait before accepting an answer?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/how-long-should-i-wait-before-accepting-an-answer)
- [Should submissions be allowed to exit with an error?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/should-submissions-be-allowed-to-exit-with-an-error)
- [Default for Code Golf: Program, Function or Snippet?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet)

---

Additionally, I think that the following should also be added to the FAQ for the reasons given with each:

- [Is it OK to promote my own posts in chat?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10184/is-it-ok-to-promote-my-own-posts-in-chat)

  This is already [part of the Chatiquette](https://ppcg.github.io/chatiquette/), but the meta post provides much more clarification and information than the single paragraph in the Chatiquette
- [Are two questions duplicates if they have different scoring rules?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/777/are-two-questions-duplicates-if-they-have-different-scoring-rules)

  A useful post for both those trying to decide whether to close as a dupe, and for those looking to see if their [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) version of a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is allowed or not. Having this is an easy to find place would be very beneficial
- [Useful External Resources](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10351/useful-external-resources)

  I think this could do with some updating, adding in some more recent resources, such as [Adám's In-Browser Language Bar](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18643/66833) or [Redwolf's various userscripts](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19402/feed-filter-a-tnb-userscript), but it's also a useful resource itself that could be helpful in the FAQ
- [General rules for custom languages and libraries](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10225/general-rules-for-custom-languages-and-libraries)

  As this is essentially a "mini" FAQ of it's own about a specific topic (similar to the [How to count bytes FAQ](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10145/how-to-count-bytes-faq)), adding it to the overall FAQ makes a lot of sense to me

---

I don't think the following posts should be added to the FAQ, as they are either too specific to merit it, or aren't "frequently asked" questions. Removing the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) is best, in my view:

- [In bash, can I use non-coreutil programs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17636/in-bash-can-i-use-non-coreutil-programs)
- [Catalogue of Catalogues](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12374/catalogue-of-catalogues)
- [How do we deal with novel emerging/recurring challenge types?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1561/how-do-we-deal-with-novel-emerging-recurring-challenge-types)

As [How are bytes counted in assembly?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12339/how-are-bytes-counted-in-assembly) is already part of the [How to count bytes FAQ](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10145/how-to-count-bytes-faq), I don't think it needs the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag, or to be added to the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

Comment: I think that even though it is in the "obvious" category, "How long should I wait before accepting an answer?" probably should not be a faq.  The accepted answer, and thus the answer all users see regardless of how they want to sort answers, does not reflect a modern position on the site and I think is actively misleading.  However I think this more or less is a frequently asked question, so it may be a good idea to ask a similar version of it for the faq.

Comment: @WheatWizard Yeah, that was one sticking point when I was deciding where to put that one. I figured that the other answer outscoring the accepted answer would probably indicate the more modern consensus, but posting a new and updated version specifically for the faq doesn't sound like a bad idea